# Spam/Stray Link in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have the following link showing up in my wordpress site:

```
<a href="http://culmorerealty.com/swinging-couple-erotic-story/">swinging couple erotic story</a>
```

When I "view source" it is showing up here:

```
<body  class="home page page-id-11 page-template-default cssstyle-style1 font-family-trebuchet font-size-is-large col12">
    <div id="rt-header">
        <div class="rt-container">
        <div class="rt-grid-12 rt-alpha rt-omega">
        <div id="text-2" class="widget widget_text rt-block">           <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://www.mmi-doc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Mission-Ministry-banner3.jpg"> <a href="http://culmorerealty.com/swinging-couple-erotic-story/">swinging couple erotic story</a> </div>
    </div><div id="text-5" class="widget widget_text rt-block">         <div class="textwidget">.</div>
```

ANY suggestions where I can find this in the WORPRESS INC files? OR other location to remove it?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you may have a hacked file. There are plugins that scan your directory to see if there are out of place files or files that have been messed with. Take a look at this one, https://wordpress.org/plugins/exploit-scanner/

Take a look at `Appearance > Widgets` to see if it created that widget that you could delete as well.